# Deploying bower_components to github

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, github, bower

I'm in the process of creating something simple and then pushing to Github. I'm using Bootstrap, Jquery and Tether all of which are in my bower_components folder. Do I just push this folder a long with my HTML files or do use Gulp to do some magic and copy the necessary files into a, let's say, a 'src' folder with the rest of the 'live' files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured it...I'm using gulp to concatenate and move the files from bower_component into corresponding folders. It's a pretty simple bit of code and I'm sure there other much more efficient ways of doing this but here's the code I've used:

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// include plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

// concatenate js files
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src(['bower_components/**/dist/*.min.js', 'bower_components/**/dist/js/*.min.js', 'bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js'])
    .pipe(concat('plugins.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

// concatenate css files
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css', 'bower_components/font-awesome/css/*.min.css'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// move font files
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src(['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.*', 'bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('fonts'));
});

// default task
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'fonts']);
```

I'm at the beginning stages of learning Gulp so if there are better ways of doing this, let me know